# Prove area of triangle with a given base and a given vertex angle is maximum when triangle is isoceles

Tags: maxima-minima

Consider the set of triangles having a given base and a given vertex angle. Show that the triangle having the maximum area will be isosceles.

I have taken $a$ and $\alpha$ to be the given base and vertex angle respectively. Area of triangle in terms of only sides is $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4b^2c^2-b^2-c^2+a^2}$ - got this from cosine formula.

Now since $b$ and $c$ are variables (while $a$ is a constant) I have taken them to be $x$ and $y$ respectively, and tried to maximise this expression $4x^2y^2-x^2-y^2+a^2$. But upon taking partial derivatives and equating them to 0, I am getting specific values of $x$ and $y$, instead of a relation as asked in the question. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a triangle with the law of sines setup/notation:

${\displaystyle {\frac {a}{\sin \alpha}}\,=\,{\frac {b}{\sin \beta}}\,=\,{\frac {c}{\sin \gamma}}}$

Recall that Angle-Angle-Side describes a unique triangle with area given by

$\tag 1 a^2 \frac{sin(\beta) sin(\gamma)}{2 sin(\alpha)}$

If both $a$ and $\alpha$ are set, we can let $\beta$ be a variable, and can write

$\tag 2 \gamma = \pi - (\beta + \alpha) $

A useful trigonometric identity allows us to write

$\tag 3 sin(\gamma) = sin(\beta + \alpha)$

To maximize (1), we can ignore the constant multiplicative factors, finding that the function

$f(\beta) = sin(\beta) sin(\beta + \alpha)$

is of interest. Using the sine angle addition identity and the sine double angle identity, you can write

$f(\beta) = cos(\alpha) sin^2(\beta) + sin(\alpha) (.5) sin(2\beta)$

Using the double angle identity again, you will find that the derivative of $f$ with respect to the variable $\beta$ is equal to

$\tag 4 cos(\alpha) sin(2 \beta) + sin(\alpha) cos(2\beta)$

If you set the expression (4) to $0$, after some algebra you can write

$\tag 5 tan(2\beta) = - tan(\alpha)$

But using the useful identity,

$tan(\pi - \theta) = -tan(\theta)$, we find that the derivative is zero when

$\tag 6 \beta = \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2}$

When $\beta$ takes this value so does $\gamma$, so we are looking at an isosceles triangle when the derivative is $0$. Examining (1) it is easy to see that this is the maximum possible area for these constrained triangles.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. This is very helpful.

Comment: I've seen max area questions where you show that an isosceles triangle must be equilateral, but your question had a different angle to it. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056026/maximum-area-of-a-isosceles-triangle-in-a-circle-with-a-radius-r

Answer (score 2):

$b$ and $c$ are variables, indeed, but they're not independent.  That's why setting the partials WRT $b$ and $c$ to zero doesn't work.

You might instead put two vertices at $(\pm \frac{a}{2}, 0)$, and then the top vertex at $(0, q)$, where $q$ is chosen to make the vertex angle be $\alpha$. (Hint: you're going to need an arctangent somewhere). That's the supposedly optimizing triangle, but what are the other possible locations for that third vertex?

Answer: Take the circle containing the three points I just described. (There's only one such circle). Then the "top" point can be at any point on the arc of the circle that's above the $x$-axis, because of a theorem about angles subtended by an arc of a circle.

NOW you've got a single variable --- the position of that third point on the upper arc of the circle --- and can use some calculus to optimize. Or you can do some nice geometric arguments and avoid the calculus altogether. :)

Comment: I solved it by calculus, using your tip. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nice answer: just enough hints for the OP to solve it, without taking all her/his fun away!

Comment: The geometric argument is really simple once you set up for the 'supposedly optimizing triangle'. I dare you to move the vertex and see what happens to the height in $A = .5 B H$!

Comment: Indeed -- symmetry is your friend here, too.

Comment: @MikeMathMan: Got it. For a fixed base and vertex angle, the height will be maximum (and hence the area), when it passes through the mid point of the base. And this will necessarily lead to two equal sides. Thank you!