Find the dimensions of the isosceles triangle of largest area that can be inscribed in a circle of radius $r$.
I have worked on the problem but I do not know where I have made a mistake. Please help me to find the mistake only.
My attempt:
To find the dimensions of the isosceles triangle of the largest area that can be inscribed in a circle of radius $r$, follow these steps:

Understanding the setup:
An isosceles triangle inscribed in a circle meaning its vertices lie on the circle.
Assume the circle has radius $r$.

Area of an Isosceles triangle:
The height of the isosceles triangle is equal to $r\cos\theta$.
The length of the base is $2r\sin\theta$.
The area of the isosceles triangle is $$\begin{align}A&=\frac{1}{2}\times\text{base}\times\text{height}
\\&= \frac{1}{2}2r^2\sin\theta \cos\theta\\&= r^2\sin\theta \cos\theta\end{align}$$

Maximum Area: Using the trigonometric identity
$\sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}\sin2\theta$, the area becomes $A = \frac{1}{2}r^2\sin2\theta$
The maximum value of $\sin2\theta$ is $1$ which occurs when $2\theta = 90^\circ$, i.e., $\theta = 45^\circ$.

Optimum dimension: When $\theta = 45^\circ$ the base subtends $90^\circ$ at the centre. The base length is $b = 2r\sin45^\circ= 2r\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}= r\sqrt{2}$. The height is $h = r\cos45^\circ = r\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.


Therefore, the dimensions of the right isosceles triangle with the largest area are: base length $=r\sqrt{2}$, and its height is $r\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Don't use \(...\) or \[...\] as this doesn't render MathJax. Use $...$ or $$...$$.

Good job in showing your attempt in detail!

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056026/maximum-area-of-a-isosceles-triangle-in-a-circle-with-a-radius-r

What is $\theta$?

Note that the height of the isosceles triangle can be $2r$, which currently isn't allowed by your parametrization of $ h = r \cos \theta$. As such, please 1/ Define $\theta$ per Math Guy's request, and 2/ Draw an image (which might indicate where an error was made).

Let triangle ABC  be inscribed in a circle of radius R with centre O

$$
\angle{BOC} = 2\angle{BAC}\\
\Delta(BOC)=\frac12(OB)(OC)\sin(\angle{BOC})=\frac{R^2}2\sin(2\angle{BAC})
$$
Similarly $\Delta(COA)=\frac{R^2}2\sin(2\angle{CBA})\quad\Delta(AOB)=\frac{R^2}2\sin(2\angle{ACB})$
We can right total area as sum of
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta(ABC)&=\Delta(AOC)+\Delta(BOA)+\Delta(COB)\\&=\frac{R^2}2(\sin(2\angle{ABC})+\sin(2\angle{BCA})+\sin(2\angle{CAB}))\\&=2R^2\sin(\angle{ABC})\sin(\angle{BCA})\sin(\angle{CAB})
\end{align}
$$
(For ease of explanation i am assuming the center lies inside the triangle same holds for the other case also)
Let $\angle{ABC} = \angle{BCA}$ be the base angles and $\angle{CAB}=A$
$$\begin{align}\text{Area}=\Delta(ABC)&=2R^2\sin(A)\sin^2(\frac{\pi-A}2)\\&=R^2\sin(A)(1+\cos (A))\end{align}$$
This has local max at $A=\frac\pi3$
So the maximum area is given by equilateral triangle with each side $R\sqrt{3}$ and $$\text{Area}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}4R^2$$

I think your mistake was when you took $h=r\cos\theta$ which ended up giving you area=$R^2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ instead of $R^2\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)$.
(PS i am not entirely sure what your $\theta$ is)
